# How can I configure libtorrent to download only specific files within a torrent, instead of downloading the entire file set?

Tags: python, libtorrent

1 .Is this the most effective way to achieve selective downloading in Python libtorrent?
2 .Are there any alternative approaches or considerations I should be aware of?
3 .Any specific code examples or guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated?

This is the code i using for download the torrent file.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Initialization

```
# Install Dependency
! pip install lbry-libtorrent

# Libraries Import
import time
import ipywidgets as widgets
import libtorrent as lt

from threading import Thread
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

# Server Start
ses = lt.session()
ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)

# Torrent States
state_str = [
    "queued",
    "checking",
    "downloading metadata",
    "downloading",
    "finished",
    "seeding",
    "allocating",
    "checking fastresume",
]

downloads = []

# Add Torrent
def add_torrent():
    params = {"save_path": "/content/drive/My Drive/Torrent"}
    link = input("Enter Magnet Link or Torrent File URL: ")
    downloads.append(
        lt.add_magnet_uri(ses, link, params)
    )

# Remove Torrent
def remove_torrent():
    i = int(input("Enter your Choice : "))
    i-=1

    for index, download in enumerate(downloads[:]):
        if (index == i) :
            ses.remove_torrent(download)
            downloads.remove(download)
            print(download.name(), "Removed")
            break
    else :
        print("Torrent not found")
    time.sleep(2.5)

# Torrent Speed
def rate(val):
    prefix = ['B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB']
    for i in range(len(prefix)):
        if abs(val) < 1000:
            if i == 0:
                return '%5.3g %s' % (val, prefix[i])
            else:
                return '%4.3g %s' % (val, prefix[i])
        val /= 1000

    return '%6.3g PB' % val


class output:
    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True
    
    # Thread Killing
    def kill(self):
        self._running = False

    # Print Status Bar
    def show(self) :
        layout = widgets.Layout(width="auto")
        style = {"description_width": "initial"}
        download_bars = [
            widgets.FloatSlider(
                step=0.01, disabled=True, layout=layout, style=style
            )
            for _ in downloads
        ]
        display(*download_bars)

        while self._running :
            for index, download in enumerate(downloads[:]):
                bar = download_bars[index]
                s = download.status()
                bar.value = s.progress * 100
                bar.description = " ".join(
                    [
                        str(index+1)+". \t",
                        download.name()[:25] +
                        "...\t|\t",
                        '%s/s | ' % rate(s.download_rate),
                        '%s/s | ' % rate(s.upload_rate),
                        '%s Done | ' % rate(s.total_done),
                        state_str[s.state],
                    ]
                )
            # time.sleep(1)
```

Main code

```
def main() :
    if downloads == []:
        print("No Torrent Found, Please add one")
        add_torrent()

    while True:
        clear_output()
        print("No  Torrent Name.    D.Speed U.Speed Downloaded  Status   Progress")

        bar = output()
        printing = Thread(target=bar.show)
        printing.start()

        time.sleep(2)

        print("[A] Add Torrent \t\t [R] Remove Torrent \t\t [Q] Quit")
        choice = input("Enter Choice : ")

        if choice.lower() == 'a':
            bar.kill()
            add_torrent()

        elif choice.lower() == 'r':
            bar.kill()
            remove_torrent()
        
        elif choice.lower() == 'q':
            bar.kill()
            print("Daemon Still Running")
            return

        else :
            bar.kill()
            print("Wrong Choice")

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

Please help for this problem

1 .Is this the most effective way to achieve selective downloading in Python libtorrent?
2 .Are there any alternative approaches or considerations I should be aware of?
3 .Any specific code examples or guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.